# What is Endpoint Discovery?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I've been using `DynamoDb` on AWS via the .NET Core SDK. I recently noticed exceptions complaining that the `AWS_ENABLE_ENDPOINT_DISCOVERY` environment variable hadn't been set - they are caught in the AWS code and there is not a noticeable functional impact.

I'm going to set this environment variable to `false` as I believe it will bring with it a performance boost, but can somebody please explain what **Endpoint Discovery** is?

For reference: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/blob/master/sdk/src/Core/Amazon.Runtime/ClientConfig.cs#L527

which leads to https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/blob/master/sdk/src/Core/Amazon.Runtime/EndpointDiscoveryEnabled.cs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Endpoint Discovery is the process where a specific URL (the "discovery endpoint") is accessed, which returns a directory of endpoints for using the system.  Other code can interrogate that directory to find the specific URLs for accessing various resources.  This allows the service host to change its URLs as needed without interfering with their client's ability to use those services.

[From Google's API docs](https://developers.google.com/discovery/v1/reference/apis):

> The Discovery Document describes the surface for a particular version of an API. The information provided by the discovery document includes API-level properties such as an API description, resource schemas, authentication scopes, and methods.

The discovery document is usually JSON or XML, and can have any structure.  Once created, the discovery document's struture can't change, otherwise it would interfere with clients.  Only the values of the endpoints can be updated.

Using Endpoint Discovery is usually optional, but you should be aware that service endpoints can change over time, breaking your code.  Using Endpoint Discovery means that your code will automatically update to the new endpoints.